# Show that the number of points of $V(I)$ is at most $m_1m_2...m_n$ if $x_i^{m_i}\in \left\langle \text{LT}(I) \right\rangle$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, groebner-basis

This is an exercise from Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et al.

> Let $I\subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ be an ideal such that for each $i$, some power $x_i^{m_i}\in \left\langle \text{LT}(I) \right\rangle$. Show that the number of points of $V(I)$ is at most $m_1m_2...m_n$.

The notation $\left\langle \text{LT}(I) \right\rangle$ means the ideal generated by the leading terms of polynomials in $I$.

**Hint**: Use the following two facts:

1. $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ is isomorphic as a $k$-vector space to $S=\text{span}(x^{\alpha}: x^{\alpha}\notin \left\langle \text{LT}(I) \right\rangle)$;
2. Let $G$ be a Groebner basis for $I$. Then with the assumption in the problem, we know that there exists some $k_i\leq m_i$ such that $x_i^{k_i}=\text{LM}(g_i)$ for some $g_i\in G$.

**My attempt**:

The monomials in $S$ could only be $x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ where $\alpha_i<m_i$.

Consider $[x_i^j]$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ where $j=0,1,...,m_i$. ***They have to be linearly dependent.***(I know this is wrong now.) So
$$\sum^{m_i}_{j=0}c_j[x_i^j]=\left[\sum^{m_i}_{j=0}c_jx_i^j\right]=[0]$$

Thus

$$\sum^{m_i}_{j=0}c_jx_i^j\in I$$

Since this is a polynomial with degree $m_i$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_i]$, it has at most $m_i$ roots. This is true for each coordinate, so $V(I)$ contains at most $m_1\cdots m_n$ points.

**Question**:

This was my first attempt. Then I realized that $[x_i^j]$ do not have to be linearly dependent. One of them could depend on some other monomials with other variables. I still think I need to end up with one variable function and use the linear dependence to show the number of roots is bounded by $m_i$. But I couldn't find them. Or is there another approach?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I'd try to argue with the properties of the gröbner basis. Isn't the point of the gröbner basis that you can express any polynomial in terms of the gröbner basis and that the order of division does not matter? 2. gives you that the number of elements in the gröbner basis is at most $m_1\cdots m_n$

Comment: @Doppelschwert: Thank you for your response! But how to connect that with the number of points in $V(I)$? Only when the polynomial in $I$ involves only one variable can we deduct information about its roots, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really know how to solve this problem. I just wanted to remind you that you skipped the second hint in your considerations so far, and I'm pretty sure you need to use it. I learned the theory of gröbner basis several years ago in a university course, so i forgot a lot of the details. Maybe I should finally read the book by cox, I've been thinking about that for some time now. Sorry I can't be of any additional help.

Comment: @Doppelschwert: Thank you anyway. I used it when I said "The monomials in $S$ could only be $x^{α_1}_1⋯x^{α_n}_n$ where $α_i<m_i$, since you have to divide $f$ by $G$ to get the unique remainder.

Comment: Ah, I see. I registered that this follows from 2., but somehow disregarded it again afterwards. By the way, I just got the 4th edition of the book and I can't find this exercise. I can, however, find an exercise that states that the number of points in $V(I)$ is at most $\dim k[x_1,...,x_n]/\sqrt{I}$. Since $I\subseteq \sqrt{I}$, your solution should follow from this other exercise, since by 1. and 2. you know that $\dim k[x_1,...,x_n]/\sqrt{I}\leq  \dim k[x_1,...,x_n]/I\leq m_1\cdots m_n$.

Comment: @Doppelschwert: In my version, this exercise is Corrollary 7, and your statement is proposition 8 that follows it. Then Corrollary 7 is left as an exercise. But now when I look at the proposition, it seems the proof didn't use corrollary 7. I'll think about that! Thanks! And by the way, I love this book.

Comment: I just looked up your statement in the book, 4th edition. I guess they reordered everything slightly, but as far as I can see it they used exactly your argument to show that it follows from $dimk[x1,...,xn]/I\leq infinity$ that $|V(I)|\leq infinity$, e.g. they argue that the monomials in a single variable $x_i$ are linearly independent and so on.

Comment: @Doppelschwert: I cannot see how that works. I can only see that $[x_i^j]$ are linearly dependent, where $j=0,1,...,m_1\cdots m_n$ by the dimension. So I will end up with a bound $(m_1\cdots m_n)^n$ using that argument. But I've figured out another way using the argument in proposition 8. I will post it as an answer later. You can post your answer if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough sketch of the proof in spoilers:

1)

> Show that $V(I)$ is finite, e.g. $V(I)=\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$

2)

> Derive the kronecker functions $\delta_{p_i}$ on $V(I)$ as polynomials $f_i$

3)

> Show that $f_i$ are linear independent in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$

Comment: That's what I just figured out! Thanks! By they way, the $f_i$'s are linearly independent, not dependent.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Glad you're on your way then :)